# nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'DPickup''

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, uisplitviewcontroller

**What I'm trying to do**: Get an SplitViewController to work for between two view controllers that pass data to each other. I'm fairly new so please provide any examples.

**The error:**
With a Thread 1: signal SIGBRT

```
Scan[29101:2468584] Unknown class MainTableView in Interface Builder file.2015-07-17 02:06:59.356 X-Scan[29101:2468584] Registering for keyboard events2015-07-17 02:08:16.944 X-Scan[29101:2468584] Unregister for keyboard events2015-07-17 02:08:16.947 X-Scan[29101:2468584] Unknown class MainTableViewin Interface Builder file.2015-07-17 02:08:16.951 X-Scan[29101:2468584] Registering for keyboard events2015-07-17 02:08:17.769 X-Scan[29101:2468584] Unregister for keyboard events
```

**I think the main concern is this**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'DPickup''
```

**What I tried:** 
Various stack overflow solutions but none seem to affect it work. I've tried  *prepareForSegue:sender* but no luck. I've also tried messing around with delegate and the managedObjectContext class, but also no luck. (hard when you're trying to debug code that has been worked on for years with no documentation).

**My Appdelegate.h Code**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "X_ScanAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([X_ScanAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

**Appdelgate.m**

```
#import "X_ScanAppDelegate.h"

@implementation X_ScanAppDelegate


@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;



// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"mom"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil) {
        NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

        [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
            [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:coordinator];
        }];
        _managedObjectContext = moc;
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSLog(@"Merging in changes from iCloud...");

    NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [self managedObjectContext];

    [moc performBlock:^{

        [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

        NSNotification* refreshNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"SomethingChanged"
                                                                            object:self
                                                                          userInfo:[notification userInfo]];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:refreshNotification];
    }];
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if((_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

    // Set up iCloud in another thread:

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you MUST change this variable:
        NSString *iCloudEnabledAppID = @"rentxent";

        // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you should change this variable:
        NSString *dataFileName = @"X-Scan.sqlite";

        /*
         NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"X-Scan.sqlite"];*/


        // ** Note: For basic usage you shouldn't need to change anything else

        NSString *iCloudDataDirectoryName = @"Data.nosync";
        NSString *iCloudLogsDirectoryName = @"Logs";
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *localStore = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];
        NSURL *iCloud = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

        if (iCloud) {

            NSLog(@"iCloud is working");

            NSURL *iCloudLogsPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudLogsDirectoryName]];

            NSLog(@"iCloudEnabledAppID = %@",iCloudEnabledAppID);
            NSLog(@"dataFileName = %@", dataFileName);
            NSLog(@"iCloudDataDirectoryName = %@", iCloudDataDirectoryName);
            NSLog(@"iCloudLogsDirectoryName = %@", iCloudLogsDirectoryName);
            NSLog(@"iCloud = %@", iCloud);
            NSLog(@"iCloudLogsPath = %@", iCloudLogsPath);

            if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]] == NO) {
                NSError *fileSystemError;
                [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                       withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                        attributes:nil
                                             error:&fileSystemError];
                if(fileSystemError != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Error creating database directory %@", fileSystemError);
                }
            }

            NSString *iCloudData = [[[iCloud path]
                                     stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];

            NSLog(@"iCloudData = %@", iCloudData);

            NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:iCloudEnabledAppID            forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
            [options setObject:iCloudLogsPath                forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey];

            [psc lock];

            [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                              configuration:nil
                                        URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:iCloudData]
                                    options:options
                                      error:nil];

            [psc unlock];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"iCloud is NOT working - using a local store");
            NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];

            [psc lock];

            [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                              configuration:nil
                                        URL:localStore
                                    options:options
                                      error:nil];
            [psc unlock];

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomethingChanged" object:self userInfo:nil];
        });
    });

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    /*

     if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
     return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
     }

     NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"X-Scan.sqlite"];

     NSError *error = nil;
     _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
     if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {


     NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
     abort();
     }

     return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
     */
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

- (void)saveContext{

}

@end
```

**My view controller header file that I'm trying to Segue to**

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {

    UITableView *tblPickups;
    UIBarButtonItem *btnClosedPickups;
    UIBarButtonItem *btnAllPickups;
    UIBarButtonItem *btnOpenPickups;
    NSMutableArray * PickupArray;
    NSMutableArray * PickupArrayAll;
    UISearchBar *searchBar;
}



@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tblPickups;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnClosedPickups;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnAllPickups;
- (IBAction)btnAllPickups_Clicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnOpenPickups_Clicked:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnClosedPickups_Clicked:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnOpenPickups;
```

**My view controllers main file**

```
#pragma mark TableView
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    EditPickupView *firstViewController =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditPickupView"];
    //[[EditPickupView alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditPickupView" bundle:nil];
    DPickup * thepickup=[PickupArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    firstViewController.thePickup=thepickup;

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Update Pickups" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;

    //[scanItemViewController setIsEditing:NO];
    //[scanItemViewController setIsListBased:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:YES];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    int rows=[PickupArray count];

    return rows;

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Set up the cell

    int therow=indexPath.row;
    DPickup * currentItem= [PickupArray objectAtIndex:therow];


    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@",currentItem.orderNumber,currentItem.clientCompany,currentItem.clientName];



    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // Updates the appearance of the Edit|Done button as necessary.

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [tblPickups setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //AppData *appdata=[AppData sharedInstance];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    AppData *app=[AppData sharedInstance];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context=[app managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        DPickup *pitem=[PickupArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        for(DPickup *itm in PickupArrayAll){
            if(itm==pitem){
                [PickupArrayAll removeObject:itm];
                [PickupArray removeObject:itm];
                break;
            }
        }

        [context deleteObject:pitem];
        [context save:nil];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:YES];

        /*
        DPickup *pitem=[PickupArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        AppData* appdata=[AppData sharedInstance];
        [appdata deletePickupItemsForPickup:[pitem getID]];
        [appdata deletePickup:[pitem getID]];

        [PickupArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        PickupArrayAll=[appdata readPickups];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:YES];
         */
    }

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
#pragma mark LifeCycle Functions


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    self.title=@"Update Pickup";
    btnAllPickups.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
    btnClosedPickups.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    btnOpenPickups.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadFetchedResults:)
                                                 name:@"SomethingChanged"
                                               object:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)visewDidUnload {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTblPickups:nil];
    [self setSearchBar:nil];
    [self setBtnClosedPickups:nil];
    [self setBtnOpenPickups:nil];
    [self setBtnAllPickups:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];


    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    AppData *appData=[AppData sharedInstance];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context=[appData managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"DPickup" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;



    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];




    PickupArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fetchedObjects];

    PickupArrayAll=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:PickupArray];

    //Pickups== [appData readPickups];
    [tblPickups reloadData];

}
- (IBAction)btnSynchClicked:(id)sender {
    AppData *app=[AppData sharedInstance];
    [app.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:nil];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [PickupArray removeAllObjects];
    for(DPickup* item in PickupArrayAll){
        if([ [item.orderNumber uppercaseString] hasPrefix:[searchText uppercaseString]] || [searchText isEqualToString:@""])
            [PickupArray addObject:item];
    }
    [tblPickups setScrollsToTop:YES];
    [tblPickups reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)btnAllPickups_Clicked:(id)sender {
    [PickupArray removeAllObjects];
    for(DPickup* item in PickupArrayAll){
            [PickupArray addObject:item];
    }
    [tblPickups setScrollsToTop:YES];
    [tblPickups reloadData];

    btnAllPickups.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
    btnClosedPickups.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    btnOpenPickups.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
}

- (IBAction)btnOpenPickups_Clicked:(id)sender {
    [PickupArray removeAllObjects];
    for(DPickup* item in PickupArrayAll){
        if([item.isPickedUp intValue]==0)
            [PickupArray addObject:item];
    }
    [tblPickups setScrollsToTop:YES];
    [tblPickups reloadData];    

    btnAllPickups.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    btnClosedPickups.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    btnOpenPickups.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
}

- (IBAction)btnClosedPickups_Clicked:(id)sender {
    [PickupArray removeAllObjects];
    for(DPickup* item in PickupArrayAll){
        if([item.isPickedUp intValue]==1)
            [PickupArray addObject:item];
    }
    [tblPickups setScrollsToTop:YES];
    [tblPickups reloadData]; 
    btnAllPickups.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    btnClosedPickups.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
    btnOpenPickups.style=UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
}

- (void)reloadFetchedResults:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSLog(@"Underlying data changed ... refreshing!");
    AppData *appData=[AppData sharedInstance];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context=[appData managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"DPickup" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;



    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];




    PickupArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fetchedObjects];

    PickupArrayAll=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:PickupArray];

    //Pickups== [appData readPickups];
    [tblPickups reloadData];

}

@end
```

I'm fairly new so if any examples or more information is needed please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @artsylar How do I fix this? the error is showing up and crashing the app.

Comment: @artsylar If you or anyone needs a full example let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to get all values of a specific type (DPickup) in a nil context.

This line is most likely setting the context to nil

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context=[appData managedObjectContext]
```

Are you sure you have setup your AppData singleton correctly?

Comment: Hey thank you for the response. I'm not because I did not do this portion of the code and I'm trying to figure it out. Do you have any suggestions or fixes that I should make?

Comment: I would suggest looking in AppData's header file and see if there is a function for registering an NSManagedObjectContext. If there is, pass the one created in the AppDelegate (the function managedObjectContext) to it. As far as I can interpret AppData, there should either be a function where you pass the context or it should create one itself (which it obviously didn't)